# Is there an option in 7-zip to split into volumes and create SFX at the same time, the SFX being later extractible on Windows without 7-zip?

Tags: windows-7, 7-zip, archiving

I use 7-zip 9.20 on Windows 7 Professional. 
When the 'Split Volume' checkbox is checked ON, SFX Archive checkbox is disabled and vice versa. 
Is there a way to accomplish both together, as well as keep the self-extracting archive extractable in Windows 7 or Windows 10 without 7-zip installed ?
What I need is, Creation of a set, something Like:
Myfilename.001, 
Myfilename.002,
Myfilename.003,
Myfilename_extract.sfx,
which can be placed in a folder and the last one does the extraction when clicked.

(I have looked at other 7-zip questions and they never handle the question of combining the two features. )I have also looked at the [only sourceforge question](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/9bc1f763/) that addresses this combination, but as on 2013, it remained on the wishlist. Any improvements since ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you right click to create an archive, and click "add to archive" you have the following two options:

[image]

This creates a split archive, starting with a file at `.001`, and for me there is also an approximately 200kB "self extractor" for it.

This is on 7-Zip 18.20. You may want to update your copy if you are still using 9.20.